# Accessing input value from an element using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

How can I check wether an input field contains any value or not from another element. My attempt,

```
<div className='input-item'>
      <input ref="accessKey" name="username" className="lci-text" type="text"/>

      <label className={"helpers" + ((this.ref.accessKey.value.length > 0) ? 'toggled' : '')}>Access Key</label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add a class '.toggled' to the label when the input has any values but getting the following error in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessKey' of undefined
```

**Update**

I've also tried `this.refs.accessKey.value.length` this time getting the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Please help me sort this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not recommended to access a `ref` directly to make changes in the same component. Additionally, since you are using react, you need make use of `this.state`.

*As a side note, you should make use of the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) `classNames`*

Below is your updated code, using React State.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.helpers{ color: red }
.helpers.toggled{ color: green }
```

**Javascript**

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {value: ''};
  },

  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  },

  render: function() {
    var toggled = this.state.value.length ? ' toggled' : '';

    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text'
          value={ this.state.value }
          onChange={ this.handleChange }
        />
        <label className={ 'helpers' + toggled }>Access Key</label>
      </div>
    );
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/qejxjo1x/2/

---

[Official Notes and References](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html):

> - **Never access refs inside of any component's render method – or while any component's render method is even running anywhere in the call
>     stack.**
> - If you want to preserve Google Closure Compiler advanced-mode crushing resilience, make sure to never access as a property what was
>     specified as a string. This means you must access using
>     this.refs['myRefString'] if your ref was defined as ref="myRefString".
> - **If you have not programmed several apps with React, your first inclination is usually going to be to try to use refs to "make things
>     happen" in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more
>     critically about where state should be owned in the component
>     hierarchy.** Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to "own" that
>     state is at a higher level in the hierarchy. Placing the state there
>     often eliminates any desire to use refs to "make things happen" –
>     instead, the data flow will usually accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No luck with 'refs' as well. Please check my update above.

Comment: @Body but you are advised not to use refs !

Answer (score 0):

use `refs` instead of `ref`:

```
this.refs.accessKey.value.length
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No luck with 'refs' as well. Please check my update above.